# Replacing text with regexp Ruby Capybara

Tags: ruby, regex, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I have a question running already linked to this problem, but this question is for a different approach.

I have a string of text on a webpage that produces includes a timestamp (hhmmss) after a transaction is complete.

I can't use Time.now as the processing time varies depending on many factors.

The text on page is:

```
"Your transaction reference number is: 0 16123 (timestamp is here) A1"
```

I'll be looking within the element to read the text in my test with:

```
expect(find(location)).to have_text trans_text
```

Could I set the location text as a variable:

```
trans_text = find(location, text: 'Your transaction reference number is: 0 16123 (timestamp is here) A1')
```

then replace the timestamp with a regex then expect that timestamp to be between two times?

I have tried doing:

```
trans_text = find(location, text: 'Your transaction reference number is: 0 16123 (\d+) A1')
```

But had no joy. I get the following error:

```
Unable to find css "#main > div > div.section-content > div.two-col.retention-success > div.second-col > div.alert-complete > p" with text "Your retention certificate number is: 0 16123 (/d+) A1".
```

How could I input a regex to replace the timestamp part of the text?

Thanks

Comment: What format is the timestamp, can you give an example? Try `(\w+)` instead of `(\d+)`, or even `(.*+)`

Comment: The format is (hhmmss).  "'Your transaction reference number is: 0 16123 120000 A1')".  strftime would be ('%H%M%S')

Comment: I've edited to add show the error I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

According to [Capybara documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method):

> text (String, Regexp) — Only find elements which contain this text or match this regexp

You have to search by regular expression (instead of a string):

```
find('p', text: /Your transaction reference number is: 0 16123 (\d+) A1/)
```

Or do verification in one step:

```
expect(page).to have_text /Your transaction reference number is: 0 16123 (\d+) A1/
```

Comment: @Tom does this help ?